# File - can't access xxx - bad address

Tags: docker, raspbian

Docker on raspbian suddenly stopped working.
I tried to restart/rebuild the image and then reinstall the docker without success.
the problem seems to come from the directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
it is impossible for me to delete its content:

```
#ls -lahR
ls: impossible d'accéder à './overlay2/a368458938936a1b2d73ee32cea474f62f1143ba85a6e0ecd15c57e6fde6efa5/diff/dev/urandom': Mauvaise adresse
ls: impossible d'accéder à './overlay2/a368458938936a1b2d73ee32cea474f62f1143ba85a6e0ecd15c57e6fde6efa5/diff/dev/zero': Mauvaise adresse
total 7,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3,5K mars  25 20:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 3,5K mars  25 20:10 ../
c????????? ? ?    ?       ?              ? agpgart
c????????? ? ?    ?       ?              ? audio
c????????? ? ?    ?       ?              ? audio1

#file *  
agpgart:    cannot open `agpgart' (Bad address)  
audio:      cannot open `audio' (Bad address)
```

filesystem is F2FS (no error) on recent SD card. 
What could be wrong ?

Comment: Looks like your filesystem is corrupt. If you haven't already got a backup now would be a very good time to try and get one. Or most of one. (A better time would have been before this started happening.)

Comment: thanks roaima, I guess you're right, but I wonder why fsck.f2fs doesn't find any errors.

Comment: Did it think the filesystem was clean? If so please add `-f` to force a check.

Comment: done with no luck, 
thanks for your help